# No effect CMAKE_MODULE_PATH (openCV cross-compiling)

Tags: c++, opencv, cmake, android-ndk, cross-compiling

Cmake doesn't see `OpenCVConfig.cmake`. Installed `list(APPEND CMAKE_MODULE_PATH "$ENV{HOME}/CLionProjects/opencv/opencv-android-shared/sdk/native/jni")`:

[image: OCV_DIR]

I want to use OpenCV in a QT application for android. Qt, OpenCV and the current project are built using the same toolchain `../Android/Sdk/ndk/android-ndk-r21e/build/cmake/android.toolchain.cmake`. Also, `ANDROID_PLATFORM=28`, `ANDROID_ABI=arm64-v8a`.
In the `CMakeLists.txt` of the current project:

```
list (APPEND CMAKE_MODULE_PATH
        "$ENV{HOME}/CLionProjects/opencv/opencv-android-shared/sdk/native/jni")
list (APPEND CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH
        ...
        "$ENV{HOME}/CLionProjects/opencv/opencv-android-shared/sdk/native/jni")
```

Cmake error:

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt: 31 (find_package):
  By not providing "FindOpenCV.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has
  asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "OpenCV", but
  CMake did not find one.

  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "OpenCV" with any
  of the following names:

    OpenCVConfig.cmake
    opencv-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "OpenCV" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "OpenCV_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files. If "OpenCV"
  provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been
  installed.
```

I suspect Cmake is looking for a specific version/platform of OpenCV, but the build settings are similar.
I also tried setting `CMAKE_MODULE_PATH` in the config line: `-DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE="/home/dym/Android/Sdk/ndk/android-ndk-r21e/build/cmake/android.toolchain.cmake" -DANDROID_ABI=arm64-v8a -DCMAKE_MODULE_PATH=/home/dym/CLionProjects/opencv/opencv-android-shared/sdk/native/jni`

Comment: Have you tried to understand the error message? CMake uses `CMAKE_MODULE_PATH` only for find script `FindOpenCV.cmake`. If you want to specify a directory where script `OpenCVConfig.cmake` is located, then set `OpenCV_DIR` variable.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Installing `OpenCV_DIR` really helped.